# Unable to connect Database

Tags: asp.net, sql

when I am trying to run my project I am getting follwing error message

> Message : Message : Message : Message
>   : Message : A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL
>   Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server

I am trying both with my local Database and Server Database, getting same error.
but when I am uploading it on my test site it works there. when I am running my another project they works fine.
please told me what I need to do run this on my local machine.

Comment: Add your ConnectionString (blank out username and password) and other SQL specific information e.g. name of SQL Server, Instance name etc.

Comment: same Connectionstring works on server, why not works on local machine?

Comment: @Marc: my connection string is:
  <add name="XYConnection" connectionString="Data Source=XYZServer;Initial Catalog=XYZDB;User ID=xyz;Password=xyz1"/>

Comment: @Marc: yes, I can access DB from my machine,username/pwd and DB exist.Remote connection also allow.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the following,

1. SQL Server should be up and running. 
       Go to All Programs >> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 >> Configuration Tools >> SQL Server  Configuration Manager >> SQL Server Services, and check if SQL Server service status is “Running”
2. Enable TCP/IP in SQL Server Configuration
        Go to All Programs >> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 >> Configuration Tools >> SQL Server Configuration Manager >> Select TCP/IP. Right Click on TCP/IP >> Click on Enable
3. Enable Remote Connection
       In SqlServer, Right click on the server node and select Properties.In the Server properties dialogbox,Go to Connections in the left pane and check “Allow remote connections to this server”

Comment: Try this,                                                         Go to Control Panel >> Windows Firewall >> Change Settings >> Exceptions  >> Add Port

Make the following entries in popup “Add a Port” and click OK.
Name : SQL
Port Number: 1433
Protocol: Select TCP